# imprimindo duas vezes com for()

Tags: c++

eu tentei fazer 1 codigo para ser possivel cadastrar varios projetos(maximo 10) e varios usuarios sendo no maximo 4 e eu queria que depois de todos cadastrados ele apresentasse eles na tela, 1 por 1, no entanto quando imprimo com mais de 1 candidato no mesmo projeto ele imprime primeiro todas as infomaçoes do projeto e depois imprime de novo com o segundo candidato e assim por diantes, segue imagem do erro e o codigo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <iostream>



 using namespace std;
 typedef struct{
     int cpf;
     string strnome;

 } informacoes;

 struct projetos{
     string strstartup;
     string strequipe;
     int valorinvestido;

 };

 int main() {
     int j,aux2;
     projetos *projeto = new projetos[10];
     cout << "digite o numero de projetos (max. 10)";
     cin >> aux2;
     while(aux2 > 10){
     cout << "por favor digite um numero menor ou igual a 10" << endl;
   aux2 = 0;
   };
   while(aux2 < 0){
   cout << "por favor digite um numero maior que 0" << endl;
   aux2 = 0;
   };



   int i,aux;
   informacoes *infos = new informacoes[4];
   cout << "digite o numero de candidatos (max. 4)";
   cin >> aux;

   while(aux > 4){
   cout << "por favor digite um numero menor ou igual a 4" << endl;
   aux = 0;
   };
   while(aux < 0){
   cout << "por favor digite um numero maior que 0" << endl;
   aux = 0;
   };
   infos[0].cpf = 0;
   infos[1].cpf = 0;
   infos[2].cpf = 0;
   infos[3].cpf = 0;

   for (j = 0; j < aux2;j++){
       cout << "por favor digite o nome da startup" << endl;
       cin >> projeto[j].strstartup;
       cout << "por favor digite o nome da equipe" << endl;
       cin >> projeto[j].strequipe;
       cout << "por favor digite o valor investido" << endl;
       cin >> projeto[j].valorinvestido;
       for (i = 0;i < aux;i++){

           cout << "digite o cpf:\n";
           cin >> infos[i].cpf;
           cout << "\ndigite o nome do componente:";
           cin >> infos[i].strnome;
           cout << "startup:["<< j+1 <<"]" << projeto[j].strstartup << endl;
           cout << "equipe:["<< j+1 <<"]" << projeto[j].strequipe << endl;
           cout << "valor investido:["<< j+1 <<"]" << projeto[j].valorinvestido << endl;
           cout << "cpf do componente:[" << i+1 <<"]:" << infos[i].cpf << endl;
           cout << "nome do componente:[" << i+1 <<"]:"<<infos[i].strnome << endl;
       }

       if(j < aux2 - 1) {
               cout << "digite o numero de candidatos (max. 4)";
               cin >> aux;
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bem, primeiramente vamos fazer isso em ponta em ponta.
Primeiro vamos fazer uma organização nesse código, começando no início... As structs Informações seria dos candidatos e a de projetos seria de cada um deles, certo?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
 #include <fstream> //Não entendi o uso da stdlib.h e da fstream
 #include <string.h>
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;
 typedef struct{ //É melhor usar typedef? Seria melhor como o modelo de projetos
     int cpf;
     string strnome;

 } informacoes; 

 struct projetos{ //Projetos de cada um
     string strstartup;
     string strequipe;
     int valorinvestido;

 };

//Seria melhor criar uma classe a projetos.
class Projetos{
      string strstartup;
      string strequipe;
      int valorinvestido;
      
      public:
            void setProjectInfo(string startup, string equipe, int investido){
                 //Coloca as atribuições para as variáveis.
            }
            //Faça uma função de receber os itens acima.
};
```

Agora vamos para a main(), tire esse j e troque aux2 para nproj para deixar mais suave.

```
int nproj;
     projetos *projeto = new projetos[10]; //Seu máximo
     projsinit: //Crie isso para usar o goto isso vai repetir até colocar o número correto.
     cout << "digite o numero de projetos (max. 10)";
     cin >> aux2;
     //Tirando o while e fazendo o seguinte.
     
     if(nproj >= 1 && nproj <= 10){ //Isso verifica se nproj está entre 0 e 11 (De 1 a 10).
         //Seguir o resto do código...
     } else{
           cout << "O números de projetos está incorreto, pode ser apenas de 1 a 10\n";
           //Use setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese"); para usar acentuação, mas precisa usar #include <locale.h>
           nproj = 0;
           //Use alguma coisa de delay para ter transição bem lenta.
           //Use system("pause"); ou use this_thread.sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000)) mas antes um #include <thread> e <chrono>.
           goto projsinit;
     }
```

As informações vai já inicializar o CPF? Pode ser ou não. Agora na parte dos candidatos faça o mesmo como fiz em projetos só que com print e limite diferente. Troque aux para ninfo e tire i.
Crie o if igual ao de projetos uma mensagem de número inválido, resetar ninfo etc.
No for() crie um int i ou j para repetir.

No for crie uma variáveis para armazenar os valores de projeto caso você usar esta classe e também para o infomações. No fim crie outro for fora desse das informações fazendo um print da lista pode fazer como está em seu código mas tente suavizar e fazer como estou dizendo. Espero que ajude.